# Powershell Get computer AD OU and compare to defined string

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am in need to get the AD OU computer belongs to and compare to specified string. I will be running the script on the pc itself with some machines running Windows 7 Embedded with Powershell v2.

I have tried the script on Windows 10 and its working fine. However, I get this error on the Embedded pc with powershell v2:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection] doesn't contain a
>   method named 'Split'.

```
    $ComputerName = $env:computername
    $Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$ComputerName))"

    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = $Filter
    $SearcherPath = $DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
    $DistinguishedName = $SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName

    $OUName = ($DistinguishedName.Split(","))[1]
    $OUMainName = $OUName.SubString($OUName.IndexOf("=")+1)

# Compare OU name to specified string
If ($OUMainName -eq "BT")
    {
        $PreferredServer=$BTServer
        $AlternativeServer=$TTServer
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am pretty new to powershell.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the line...

```
$DistinguishedName = $SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName
```

is returning an object of the type...

```
[System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection]
```

And that object type does not support the split method.  I think you are probably interested in the stringified output from the AD object so you just need to convert the name property into a string before splitting, either at time of storage into the variable or at time where the split takes place like this...

**At variable storage**

```
$DistinguishedName = ($SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName).tostring()
```

**At Split invocation**

```
$OUName = ($DistinguishedName.tostring().Split(","))[1]
```

That said, I'm not quite sure if you are only getting to the PropertyValueCollection object that you won't need to additionally select the specific Value property of the target Property (OU or path probably?) before you can convert it into a string.

Comment: Hi Trey, thanks for your quick input. I thought it will be something like this. I converted the object to string at Split invocation and its working fine now on both systems (Win 10, Win 7 embedded). Again thanks for your help :-)